# what happens to a javascript variable assign with a non existent variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm assigning a javascript variable with a value as

```
var newline = $("#newline").val();
```

The `$("#newline").val()` may or may not exist (in some cases, the `#newline` may not exist in the DOM, or even if it exists, it may not have any value).

I want to check whether the `var newline` is set or not. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes down to "What does the jQuery `val` method return if there are no elements matching the selector in the DOM?"

The answer to that is `undefined` so:

```
if ( typeof newline === "undefined" ) {

}
```

Comment: It will return an empty string though when the selector does match some elements but the first matched element has no `value` attribute. From jQuery 1.6, you can use `$('...').prop('value')` if you want to differentiate between an empty value and no value at all ([prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) always returns undefined if there is no value attribute).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
(function() {
    if (this && this[0] && this[0].value) {
        // Has a value
    } else {
        // Has no value    
    }    
}).call($("#newline"));
```

`this[0]` is the HTML Element itself, rather than a jQuery Object.

Pure JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    if (this && this.value) {
        // Has a value
    } else {
        // Has no value    
    }    
}).call(document.getElementById("newline"));
```

Comment: If there isn't an element that that id, then you will be trying to access a properly belonging to an undefined variable, which will error and terminate the script.